# Mass Effect 3 (Gibbed Save Editor) - What's Diana Allers Romance ID?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I recently romanced Diana Allers, after which we consummated our relationship. 
Now I would like to use the "Gibbed save editor" to change the status of the relationship so that I can pursue other women in the game. I've been searching on different forums, and they seem to have the Romance ID for all characters except for Diana!

What is the Romance ID/Bool for Diana Allers?

Answer (score 1):

Diana Allers' love flag is 19835.

PlotID Clear: 19835

Comment: Mark, That's not it... To remove any traces of you doing allers, change these bools to false:
- 20628
- 20639 Note you must do this before Liara (if romancing) confronts you, otherwise it is too late. Alternatively, just reload a save after it happened.